# After we elect new moderators what will the changing of the guard look like?

Tags: discussion, moderation

In general I'm wondering how the power shift works once the new mods are elected:

- Will the new mods go to work immediately?
- Is there any structured training or is it all "on-the-job" training?
- Will SE's team still be minding the store, stepping in when needed?

Sorry, if answers to these kinds of questions are documented somewhere already, this is my first SE Beta and I'm trying to get a picture of what to expect in the coming weeks.

Comment: To clarify, this site won't get an election till we graduate. The whole time we're in public beta, we'll have "pro tempore" (English: "temporary" or "interim") moderators, who are appointed by SE staff. When ( *not if* ) we make it to graduation, then we'll have a regular democratic election, with all users with a certain amount of rep eligible to vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will the new mods go to work immediately?

Yes, it will start as soon as the the SE staff deems the election period is over.

> Is there any structured training or is it all "on-the-job" training?

As far as I can tell, [it's all on-the-job training](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/410/how-do-sites-train-moderators-if-at-all).

> Will SE's team still be minding the store, stepping in when needed?

Of course! The SE staff is involved with all SE sites to some extent, more so in betas like this one.

---

As for any "power shift", yes the moderators will gain access to some new tools and hold a higher status than they currently hold, but the community is still in control of the scope and such. Moderators are put in place to enforce standards set by SE and by the community they're a moderator on as well as to deal with problematic users, spam, etc.

For more information about moderation, check out [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/215485) and [Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq)

Comment: Good, so after the election Abby will still be around to keep you in line.

Comment: @apaul34208 I sure hope so ;)

Comment: Spam can also be handled by relatively low-rep users... after all 6 Spam flags nuke any post and add a 100 reputation penalty.

Comment: @Vogel612 I think you may be commenting on the wrong thread?

Comment: You explicitly mentioned spam... while this is a part of moderator duty it is something that can also be done by actve community members. I just wanted to clarify that ;)